# Python Regular epressions

Tags: python, regex

I would very much appreciate if any one could explain what is wrong with me regex.I tried it on a regex generator works perfectly but while compiling on my laptop it prints out None.
i am given a html link and i would like to identify its href(reference)Here is the regex

```
r"(?<=\=\").{1,}(?=\W+?\s[t])"
```

example:

```
<li id="n-mainpage-description"><a href="/wiki/Main_Page" title="Visit the main page [z]" accesskey="z">Main page</a></li>
```

error:

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] by including your code and the specific input you used that caused the error.

Comment: @SuperStormer The question was poorly formatted but OP did forget to supply the error which they received

Comment: You might be trying to load a page with javascript which doesn't have the html tags visible without rendering.

Comment: Are you using `re`'s `match` instead of `search`?

Comment: Don't try to use regex to parse HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of negative lookbehind to get the contents of an href:

```
(?<=href=\")[^\"]+
```

- `(?<=href=\")` - make sure an `href="` precedes my current position
- `[^\"]+` - capture everything which is not a double quote

https://regex101.com/r/NDVDNB/1